# How to count the instances of unique values in Python Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like below where I have 2 million rows. The sample data can be found [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Z5No3M-z_WfOcrR0cmnqiBXexMdvHNu7saQ7jcKCm08/edit?usp=sharing).

[image]

The list of matches in every row can be any number between 1 to 761. I want to count the occurrences of every number between 1 to 761 in the matches column altogether. For example, the result of the above data will be:

[image]

If a particular id is not found, then the count will be 0 in the output. I tried using for loop approach but it is quite slow.

```
def readData():
    df = pd.read_excel(file_path)

    pattern_match_count = [0] * 761
    for index, row in df.iterrows():
        matches = row["matches"]

        for pattern_id in range(1, 762):
            if(pattern_id in matches):
                pattern_match_count[pattern_id - 1] = pattern_match_count[pattern_id - 1] + 1
```

Is there any better approach with pandas to make the implementation faster?

Comment: please provide a reproducible self-sufficient input, not images

Comment: What is the data type of the matches column?

Comment: list is the datatype of the matches column

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`.explode()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html) method to "explode" the lists into new rows.

```
def readData():
    df = pd.read_excel(file_path)
    return df.loc[:, "count"].explode().value_counts()
```

Comment: Just a note that you can apply explode to the series directly which may save memory for a large dataframe `df.loc[:, "matches"].explode().value_counts()`

Comment: @Andrew Thanks. Selecting then applying is better memory-wise than applying then selecting. I have edited my answered and corrected a little typo you made in your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"matches": [[1,2,3],[1,3,3,4]]})

#df:
#        matches
#0     [1, 2, 3]
#1  [1, 3, 3, 4]

from collections import Counter

C = Counter([i for sl in df.matches for i in sl])
#C:  
#Counter({1: 2, 2: 1, 3: 3, 4: 1})

pd.DataFrame(C.items(), columns=["match_id", "counts"]) 
#   match_id  counts
#0         1       2
#1         2       1
#2         3       3
#3         4       1
```

If you want zeros for `match_id`s that aren't in any of the matches, then you can update the `Counter` object `C`:

```
for i in range(1,762):
    if i not in C:
        C[i] = 0
pd.DataFrame(C.items(), columns=["match_id", "counts"])
```